# BitmapImage Failing when trying to change image on a trigger c# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, bitmapimage

I am trying to dynamically change the page I am on biased off of an event in a UWP application. When the even is triggered I check a simple if statement which passes and I try to set the old back ground image to a new one. I dumbed down my code to where I put the exact url (see image of file structure) in to where the image is located, but I still get an error. Bellow is the error:

Error: System.ArgumentException: 'Error 0x2624.  Debugging resource strings are unavailable. See [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.30319.0&File=mscorrc.dll&Key=0x2624"](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.30319.0&File=mscorrc.dll&Key=0x2624%22)

Here is The Affected Code:

```
c# -- MainPage.xmal.cs
BackGroundImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Images/Financial.png", UriKind.Relative));

XMAL --MainPage.xmal
<Image x:Name="BackGroundImage" Source="Assets/Images/Food.png" />
```

File Structure:

[image]

Whenever I trigger the even that changes the background I get the error and the program crashes. Does anyone have any idea why? This is my first time playing around with BitmapImages and Uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, please try to change the URL schemes.

Like the following:

```
BackGroundImage.Source= new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Images/Financial.png"));
```

For more details about URL schemes in UWP, please refer to this:[URI schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes#ms-appx-and-ms-appx-web)